# xsl:result-document is disabled when extension functions are disabled

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-camel, saxon

I want to have multiple file output with xsl so I'm using xsl:result-document and I'm having this error

**xsl:result-document is disabled when extension functions are disabled**

It seems that I need to enable the external functions so that it works. But the problem is that I am not using command line, I can't just put **-ext:on**. Here I am calling xslt with camel and spring XML. If I understood well, I need to change the configuration properties of xslt so that the allow-external-functions is set to true.

Here is what I tried to fix it :

```
<bean id="xslt-saxon" class="org.apache.camel.component.xslt.saxon.XsltSaxonComponent">
        <property name="saxonConfiguration">
          <bean class="net.sf.saxon.Configuration"/>
        </property>
        <property name="saxonConfigurationProperties">
          <map>
            <entry key="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/allow-external-functions" value="true" value-type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
          </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And then when I call xslt-saxon :

```
<to uri="xslt-saxon:file://{{format.transformer.file}}"/>
```

But it doesn't work, the error is :

```
No component found with scheme: xslt-saxon
```

Even if I add dependency to saxon in my pom.xml it doesn't work.
I don't know what to try next, do you have any idea ?

**EDIT** :

Now there is no more error when using xslt-saxon, but the first error is still there. It is as the map for allow-external-functions didn't work.

Comment: I've added the apache-camel tag, since it seems apache-camel is being used to configure the Saxon configuration so that's where you problem lies.

Comment: Please don't say "it doesn't work": say how it fails.

Comment: sorry, the error says : No component found with scheme: xslt-saxon

Comment: Did you also try the [`saxonConfiguration`](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/xslt-saxon-component.html) parameter?

Comment: Well I didn't find any example the saxonConfiguration, if you see my code, I am mentionning it and I am setting the saxonConfigurationProperty. That's everything I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to **run an XSL transformation with Saxon through Camel** by just sending a message with an XML body to

```
.to("xslt:transformation.xsl?saxon=true")
```

No Spring XML needed or enabling of external functions, it just works when I add the dependency

```
<artifactId>camel-saxon</artifactId>
```

By the way, I am on Camel 2.17.

---

My example input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Camel>
    <Component>
        <XSL>The XSL component</XSL>
        <File>The file component</File>
    </Component>
</Camel>
```

My transformation.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Camel-Components>
            <xsl:for-each select="Camel/Component/*">
                <xsl:result-document href="test-{position()}.txt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Camel-Components>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me two new files, notice the **dynamic filename** defined as `test-{position()}.txt`

- `test-1.txt` => contains `The XSL component`
- `test-2.txt` => contains `The file component`

Both files are created in the same path where my transformation stylesheet is saved since I just provide a filename and no path.

Comment: I am using Camel 2.17

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am basically doing the same but I still get the same error. What camel-saxon version are you using ?

Comment: My camel-saxon version is also 2.17, to be exact 2.17.1. You should never mix different Camel versions for the different components, so camel-core and camel-saxon are the same version

Comment: Well I have tried changing the version but it still does the same.

Comment: Well thank you, the problem was just that I put the ?saxon=true at the wrong place.

Comment: Ups, yeah, then it uses the default XSL transformer, Xalan I guess